# Best way to store requests data

Tags: sql-server, database, performance, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to save requests data (main data : request id, date, url. additional data : headers and bodies). 
Currently it's store in my databse with only 1 table. 
The biggest part of memory take additional data. So when it will be to many requests stored, here can be problem with performance. 
Is there any way to store additional data separately from main data? or any other advices?

Thanks.

---

Work with ASP.Net MVC4 and Ms SQL Server 2012.

Comment: SQL server is made to store large amounts of data.  If you are having performance issues, you need to reduce data being returned via nonclustered indexes or partitioned tables.

Comment: Why do you want to log the request to a database anyway? IIS already logs requests, you just need to set the proper settings in IIS Manager

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, i need to show them on web page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The software like Apache web server stores access info in log files (access.log). You could probably implement something similar. Then you can rotate your logs daily.

This way you have your data separated and filesystem storage is really fast, so performance won't be a problem. The problem comes when you have to do some advanced querying on your log.

You could probably use ELMAH: https://code.google.com/p/elmah/ and set it to store info in XML.

Comment: thanks, i was thinking about xml files, but log-files may be better.